# Sql server 2008 covert float to varchar gives me wrong data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having an issue altering a table

I am trying to convert a column from float to varchar

```
alter table table_name alter column telephone varchar(12)
```

As a result I am getting exponential and decimal phone numbers like this

7.12343e+003

How can I correct this? I want my column schema to be varchar since I want to format the telephone a certain way

Thank you

Comment: Formatting the phone # should be done in the presentation layer, not the database.

Comment: Also, 12 characters isn't enough for global usage especially if you are formatting the # at the database level.

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately the system we are using is already setup that way.I tried using a number higher than 12, gave me the same problem. I solved the problem using the answer below. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you add another field name and update using `STR()` function?

```
UPDATE table_name
SET new_varchar = STR(telephone);
```

Comment: that works. Just created that new column drop the old one and renamed the new one. I was just wondering if there was a one step solution for this problem. Thanks anyways man.